# How can I pass a method as an argument in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, methods, arguments, argument-passing

I am passing a method as an argument to a called function:

```
def my_function(args1)
   puts args1
end

def my_calling_method
   self.my_function(def do_this 
             return 2*3
           end)
end
```

When I call `my_calling_method` which makes a call to `my_function`, I am getting `args1` as nil instead of `def do_this return 2*3 end`.

Am I doing anything wrong? Can we pass method as an argument in Ruby?

Alright, I tried implemented a Proc for my requirement now but I am having a hard time to pass it to the calling method.

```
my_Proc = Proc.new do
    return 2*3
end

def my_calling_method
    self.my_function
end

def my_function my_Proc
   my_Proc.call
end
```

The reference material I used passes a Proc as an argument to the method like I do, but I am getting error, zero arguments passed to my_function as I am not passing any argument through my_calling_method.

Comment: Look into passing blocks to a method (and look into Procs and Lambdas). I think that is what you are looking for.

Comment: @CharlesCaldwell exactly true you are saying..

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? It almost looks like you are expecting to get the string "def do_this return 2*3 end". Are you just trying to see if you can pass in a method and just using `puts` to debug whether you can?

Comment: I am trying to execute "def do_this return 2*3 end" from my_function method for my specific requirement. I am learning Procs and Lambda to see how it actually works and will use it in my methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Defining a new method will not return a value. (Much like writing down a phone number does not result in a conversation.)

```
irb:001>def something
irb:002>   # code here
irb:003>end
=> nil
```

When you run that in IRB, you get `nil`, right? So, if you **define** that method as part of a method call:

```
some_method( def something; stuff; end )
```

You are getting back `nil` from the method definition and hence `nil` is what gets passed into `some_method`.

Without knowing exactly what it is you are trying to accomplish, I will tell you that you can pass methods, or what are called "blocks", into your method call.

```
def my_function(&block)
  puts block.call
end

my_function {2*3}
#=> 6
my_function {t = Time.now; t + 8640}
#=> 2013-08-09 14:03:29 -0500
my_function do 
   name = "Charlie"
   name.downcase.reverse.capitalize
end
#=> Eilrahc
```

In fact, this is what you are doing (more or less) with the method `.each`

```
array.each {|ele| foo}
```

I recommend reading up on Ruby's block, Procs, and Lambdas for passing methods in as arguments.

Comment: That phone number thing is so true, as my dating life will attest.

Comment: Maybe putting `{}` around your phone number when you hand it out will help them `.call` you. ;)

Comment: I updated the question with Proc. But my method is not able to refer the Proc. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Now you have a scope problem. Since `my_Proc` is defined outside `my_calling_method`, the method can't see it. You'll have to first pass `my_Proc` into `my_calling_method` and then from there pass it into `my_function`. Methods are closed rooms. They see nothing outside unless you bring it into the room. You can make `my_Proc` into `@my_Proc` and use `def my_function; @my_Proc.call; end` but it is considered bad form.

Comment: Note that whereas methods are closed rooms, Procs and Lambdas have open floor plans. They see everything up until the moment they are defined.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong. A method definition returns `nil`. The value of `def do_this; return 2*3 end` is `nil`. That is what you get.

Comment: Shouldn't args1 = def do_this return 2*3 end?

Comment: Yes, exactly. And that is `nil`.

Comment: @tech_learning When you **define** a method, you get `nil`. When you **call** a method, you get the returned value.

Comment: @tech learning: No, the act of defining a method (via keyword `def`) is not the same thing as what `def` returns. Probably you want a `Proc`, lambda or even just Ruby's default block handling to do what you want. It depends on how you intend to generate and call your passed-around code